# How to make columns auto resize?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with two columns. I am creating it with flask and html.

I want the columns to display like this. It displays like this on screens with wide enough resolution:
[image: The form is on the side of the table]

However, on screens with lower resolution, it displays like this:
[image: The table is below the form]

I quite dislike this and would like to make it so that it will always display like the first image. I think the solution would to make the columns auto resize but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The form and table are contained in columns like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="sidenav">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Form in here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="custom-container container">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="about-section">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
                    <!-- Table in here -->
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be fantastic. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<div class="custom-container container">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="about-section">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
      <!-- Table in here -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

by this:

```
<div class="col-12">                          <!-- here -->
  <div class="custom-container container">    <!-- here -->
    <div class="about-section">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- delete <br /> and add a margin-bottom to about-section -->
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
      <!-- Table in here -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are using a UI framework (Bootstrap) and the correct method is :

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-2">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer but with a Grid layout.  See if you can modify to your needs.

```css
 .wrapper > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
 }
 .wrapper {
   max-width: 1200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 0.25rem; 
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; );
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h1> Form </h1>
      <!-- Form in here -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1> Table </h1>
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
        <!-- Table in here -->
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```